# How to interpret agglomerative coefficient agnes() function?

Tags: r, clustering

how to interpret agglomerative coefficient in agnes() function of cluster package?

Example:

```
res.agnes <- agnes(dataset,method = 'ward')  
res.agnes$ac  
0.934
```

Comment: how you said that distance is 20!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you are facing a concrete problem. Anyway, here it goes a definition of the agglomerative coefficient, from [Finding Groups in Data: An Introduction to Cluster Analysis](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9780470316801):

> Generally speaking, the AC describes the strength of the clustering
>   structure that has been obtained by group average linkage. However,
>   the AC tends to become larger when n increases, so it should not be
>   used to compare data sets of very different sizes.

Also, if you are familiar with the silhouette,

> The AC can also be compared to the silhouette coefficient (SC)

First sight, the coefficient you get points to a pretty reasonable cluster structure in your data, since it is closed to 1: the coefficient takes values from 0 to 1, and it is actually the mean of the normalised lengths at which the clusters are formed. That is, the lengths you see when you look at your dendogram.

**EDIT after comments**: indeed it can be misleading that the text in the book I referenced ("Finding Groups in Data...") refers in my copy-paste to the group average linkage. However, the coefficient refers to the banner (which is like a kind of simpler or binary dendogram) and just validates the structure that the clustering produces, regardless of the method.

[This](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/cluster/html/coef.hclust.html) is another reference to the agglomerative coefficient with no reference to the method used (although of course always in the context of hierarchical clustering).

**EDIT 2 after comments**: I explain below my understanding on how the coefficient is calculated, always using the same reference.

The formula for the coefficient is

$$AC = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i} l(i)$$

i.e. the mean of the `l(i)`, calculated as follows:

> For each object i, we look at the line containing its label and
>   measure its length I(i) on the 0-1 scale above or below the banner.

Although I could not make the plot with 0-1 scale, it is just a normalization of the lengths.

The banner is a binary representation of the dendogram, where:

- in the left side, when all objects are separated in the initial stage of the agglomerative algorithm, the banner is just blank
- as soon as 2 objects get together in the same cluster, they appear in the banner
- the `l(i)` are marked by the points in the x axis in which the objects get together, and are the lengths of the horizontal bars of the plots

Always clearer with an example, actually taken to a similar one in the same book.
Let's imagine 5 objects in a space of 4 dimensions; 4 of the objects very closed together, and one of them far away.

```
df <- data.frame("c1"=c(2, 2, 2, 2, 10), "c2"=c(2, 2, 2, 2, 10),
                 "c3"=c(2, 2, 2, 2, 10), "c4"=c(2, 2, 2, 2, 10))
```

Let's do the clustering,

```
library(cluster)
r <- agnes(df, method="ward")
```

The bannerplot actually looks a bit ugly:
[image: bannerplot]

but anyway, in there the 4 objects that are at the same position are joined at the beginning in a cluster, and the 5th is at distance 20. Personally, it is much easier to look at the dendogram:
[image: dendogram]

however the information is pretty much the same.

Now the AC calculation. The lengths of the bars are 1 (normalized) for the first 4 objects, and 0 for the last one, thus the AC is 0.8:

```
> r$ac
[1] 0.8
```

In the dendogram, one should imagine the bars rotated 90 degrees, and they go from the root of the tree to the point in which the groups are formed.

Comment: But he used ward, not group average linkage.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse edited my answer. If you disagree please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: The book says "AC is the average width of the banner", which appears to be a kind of average (and normalized to 0:1) height of the dendrogram, but the actual way it is computed is unclear to me.